ERC proposal for Digital Product Passports
I'm looking to start an ERC proposal for Digital Product Passports.  My company provide me free time to contribute to Open Source and I'm looking to work on this subject. On my point of view Digital Product Passports are in the route of collision with Blockchain and I wish to create this standard to Digital Product Passport.
I have worked towards the NFT use cases for the DPP but it dont seems to be the best approach in terms of storage.
I started to look on how to start an ERC proposal and get some guidance and the docs mentioned to come here as an starting point.
Here is some information about the
DPP: https://www.europarl.europa.eu/cmsdata/281452/05.1.a.%20EPRS_STOA_STUD_757808_DPP_textile_DraftPanel.pdf
My point of view is having and composable smart contract similar to the composable NFTs proposal.
Any help or guidance would be appreciated.
Thank you

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are talking about nor did i have the courage to read through this big paper of yours. How out of the top of my head, would ERC6551 be a solution to what you are looking into ?

I’m voting to close this question because this is not the right place to discuss ERCs. You can check https://ethereum-magicians.org/new for ERC proposals.

Hi @ZartajAfser  that is interesting the documentation says to discuss the topics here first, because of this I came here. As per I understood ethereum-magicians is for another kind of EIPs, as for example changes at the protocol level.

Thanks @Torof , so that would not fit properly with the DPP requirements.  It needs to keep the records of the entire product lifecycle as for example it's origins, manuals, components.  I did a POC storing the metadata on a NFT linking to an IPFS json.  But it dont seems to be the optimal way.

ERCs are discussing Ethereum, the blockchain itself.
Digital Product Passport is out of the scope of Ethereum.
I am not aware of any good Internet forum for discussing Digital Product Passports. You would need to first collect the users of such product to a single forum and discuss it there. I guess in this case it would be the companies in textile industry.
I suggest you can start a Github repository with an example implementation.

I don't understand the statement "Digital Product Passport is out of the scope of Ethereum" Does that mean that only financial products are on the scope of Ethereum?

I suggest you look the existing ERCs to a get a feeling what kind of proposals are usually handled in this process.

In a sense, anyone can submit anything to ERC process. However because people working on ERCs do not know about Digital Product Passport, or it is not relevant for Etheruem ecosystem, it is unlikely anyone is able to help, give feedback on your proposal or and there is unlikely to be champion to make it a accepted EIP.
